# Requiring generic instances (for higher-kinded type constructors) in instance context

Tags: haskell, typeclass, higher-rank-types

I'm trying to create a flexible representation for an inductive datatype (that describes a version of the lambda calculus with datatypes and pattern matching). The flexibility here should mean that it is easy to add extra data on the nodes (free comonad-style) or to do substitution (free monad-style). So here's what I have:

```
type Tie f φ = φ (f φ)

type Id = String
type Var = Id
type Con = Id

data Pat φ = PVar Var
           | PCon Con [Tie Pat φ]
           | PWildcard

data Expr φ = EVar Var
            | ECon Con
            | EApp (Tie Expr φ)
            | ELam (Tie Pat φ) (Tie Expr φ)
```

The trouble comes when I want to derive the `Show` instance. Of course, I can do something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance (Show (φ (Pat φ))) => Show (Pat φ)
deriving instance (Show (φ (Expr φ)), Show (φ (Pat φ))) => Show (Expr φ)
```

but writing out the context by hand becomes unwieldy when the inductive structure becomes more complex.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
deriving instance (forall a. Show (φ a)) => Show (Expr φ)
```

to express that the functor φ should be, in some sense, "transparent" to the Show instance.

Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: I have never seen "forall" allowed in a superclass context.

Comment: Now we have `Show1` and `QuantifiedConstraints`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would involve

```
class Show1 f where
  showsPrec1 :: Show a => Int -> f a -> ShowS
```

This type class is similarly defined in `prelude-extras`.  Unfortunately, Haskell's deriving mechanism would not take advantage of it, and could therefore not be used.  A possible replacement may be using the new `GHC.Generics` and `DefaultSignatures` to create, though not "derived", at least trivial instances.

```
instance (Show1 φ) => Show (Pat φ)
instance (Show1 φ) => Show (Expr φ)
```

Now for the difficult part: actually using `GHC.Generics`.  What could be used is

```
instance (Show1 f, Show a) => Show (f a) where showsPrec = showsPrec1
```

However, this has the extreme disadvantage of requiring `OverlappingInstances` (in addition to other problems).  One possible solution is to define a class that is shadows `Show`.

```
class Show' a where showsPrec' ...
instance (Show1 f, Show' a) => Show' (f a) where ...
```

If all the `GHC.Generics` machinery was in place (`GShow`, `GShow1`, default signatures, etc.), then the end result would not look too horrible.

```
instance (Show1 φ) => Show' (Pat φ)
instance (Show1 φ) => Show (Pat φ) where showsPrec = showsPrec'
instance (Show1 φ) => Show' (Expr φ)
instance (Show1 φ) => Show (Expr φ) where showsPrec = showsPrec'
```

However, pretending that the amount of work required isn't that bad (it is pretty bad), some types would have to be manually set to forward from `showsPrec'` to `showsPrec` (`Char`, `Bool`, etc.), and all types used would have to be made instances of `Show'`, which, though trivial if an instance of `Generic` or `Generic1`, is certainly not convenient.